# Click span element using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I would like to know how can I click on this element using selenium:

```
<span data-val="BB9049_600"> 7.5 </span>
```

Since there is no class or id with the span element I cant approach it that way.
The xpath is:

```
//*[@id="buy-block"]/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/span
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use text content of required element as

```
//span[normalize-space()="7.5"]
```

or value of `data-val` attribute:

```
//span[@data-val="BB9049_600"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css selector as below

```
driver.findelement(By.CssSelector("[data-val='BB9049_600']"))
```

also by looking at 'data-val' value it seems 600 in 'BB9049_600' is not a constant value if that is the case then you can use below to check if selector starts with value

```
driver.findelement(By.CssSelector("[data-val^='BB9049_']"))
```